# Using ADO.NET to show a database on a different webpage in VB 2008

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2008, gridview, ado.net

I am having some trouble knowing if this framework I have would be the correct way to show all users and their roles in a table in gridview in VB 2008. I have everything laid out I just need to make sure the code behind is correct. I have an initial page with a user login and password and one button, which granted the correct info is entered, will lead to the next page which accesses the database and produces a table of all the users and their roles in gridview.

Take a look at the code and please let me know if this is right idea.

```
Dim mySqlConnection As SqlConnection

mySqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;" _
+"Password=myPassword; " _
    +"Persist Security Info=True;" _
    +"User ID=mcobery;" _
    +"Initial Catalog=model;")

Try
    mySqlConnection.Open()
    Console.WriteLine("Opened Connection to {0}",_
        mySqlConnection.ConnectionString)

' Close the connection explicitly
mySqlConnection.Close()
Console.WriteLine("Closed Connection. " _
    +"It is important to close connections explicitly.")

Catch
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Open Connection to {0}", _ 
        mySqlConnection.ConnectionString)

End Try
```

As you can see, this is a framework that I will fill in with the correct username and password.

Please let me know if this is correct code behind.

Comment: Thanks DBD all that SHOUTING was doing me in

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know where to start here.

First thing

```
Using myConnection as new SqlConnection(someConnectionString)
  myConnection.Open()
  ...

End Using
```

When myConnection goes out of scope it will get closed, well actually it will go back in to the connection pool. You need to read up on that.

The GC will tidy up for you, but as basic priniciple, what closes your connection if you get an exception? You said it was very important in your comment.

You create a connection, you do something, you close it, it goes out of scope, so why are you persisting security info?

Don't put your passwords in the code. They should be in the config. In fact all your connection string should. That would also help out, when you want to test in a staging environment. Or when the system boys tell you sql server and IIS are on different machines.

Why are you using sql server security by the way?

How are you going to unit test this?

Keep going there are plenty far more experienced than yourself making worse mistakes than these. If I were you though I'd pick up a best practices book. Some of it will go over your head until you learn a bit more, but get a sense of the dos and don'ts.